# specify regex for alternating between strings?

Tags: regex

1. Given n arbitrary strings, s1, ..., sn, how can I specify a RegEx
   that  can match all the strings?
   For example,

   > I am not smart.

   If I want to match `am` and `ar`, I can use `a[mr]`.

   But if I want  to match `am` and `not`, I don't know how, because
   brackets can only specify a set of characters, not a set of strings.
2. Another example,  How can I match both `a*` and `b*`? Are there any
   particular way for this particular example?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do... especially with #2, you want to match 0 or more a's and b's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [capturing or *non-capturing*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) group to separate your expressions with the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
(am|not)    # group and capture to \1: 'am' OR 'not'
(?:am|not)  # group, but do not capture: 'am' OR 'not'
```

---

To match **`a`** or **`b`** followed by the `*` quantifier meaning (`0` or more times) ...

```
(a|b)*      # group and capture to \1 (0 or more times): 'a' OR 'b'
(?:a|b)*    # group, but do not capture (0 or more times): 'a' OR 'b'
```

Or using a character class:

```
([ab]*)     # group and capture to \1: any character of: 'a', 'b' (0 or more times)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match a specific and defined set of words, you can have them fully typed out and separated with the OR operator, `|`:

```
(am|not|smart)
```

Pending the language you're using, you'll need to specify different flags to capture them individually, but "all" of them. In javascript, for instance, you would use `g`:

```
str.match(/(am|not|smart)/g);
```

Whereas in PHP you would simply use the `preg_match_all()` function:

```
preg_match_all('/(am|not|smart)/', $str, $matches);
```

If you're looking to match "all words", i.e. "any *word*", you can use the word-boundary `\b`:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b
```

This, of course, can be modified to accept punctuation or numeric values as well.

Regarding your second question, you hinted at the ability to do it in the first with a matching-set (i.e. characters within brackets). To capture any `a` or `b` character followed by anything else:

```
([ab].*)
```

If you want them to *have* to be followed by other letters (which can be expanded from here):

```
([ab][a-z]+)
```